# How to use MediaRecorder to encode videos not from Camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an application that generate an animation with many video frames.

I wanna to encode these frames into a video.

If these frames were from the default video camera I could encode them using MediaRecorder API.

QUESTION 1:
How to encode a video from frames that aren't from video camera using the MediaRecorder?

I already thought in create a FakeCamera class that extends android.hardware.Camera, but it wasn't possible, I also try extends MediaRecorder, but I don't know what to do.

QUESTION 2:
Is the only solution use ffmpeg? Any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

On some devices it is, e.g. Samsung Galxy S, it is impossible (without rooting) to encode frames that do not come from built-in camera., at least using h/w codecs. They are just designed like that.

Using built-in s/w codecs is not worth the pain of finding out the way IMHO. S/w codecs (like ffmpeg) provided by you should have comparable performance.